# NSCountedSet enumeration in Swift

Tags: swift3, enumeration, nscountedset

I'm looking for a way to use `NSCountedSet` in a more `Swift`-like way (whatever that means).

Consider the following snippet that I basically translated directly from `Objective C`. I iterate over each symbol (a `String`) in the set, get its corresponding count, and look up a value for that symbol in a dictionary. Then I multiply that value with the count and add it to the total.

```
var total = 0

for symbol in symbolSet {
    let count = symbolSet.count(for: symbol)
    let item = symbolDictionary[symbol as! String]
    let value = item?.value

    total+= (count * value!)
}
```

It works, but I am a bit concerned about the unwrapping that `Xcode` suggested for me. So I am trying to do this a more `Swift` like way so that it is more safe without all the unwrapping.

I started with something like this:

```
symbolSet.enumerated().map { item, count in
    print(item)
    print(count)
}
```

But count here is not the actual count, but an enumeration index.

How do I move forward with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could chain a `flatMap` followed by a `reduce` operation on your `symbolSet`,

- The `flatMap` operation applies attempted conversion of the `symbolSet` members to `String`
- The following `reduce` operation computes the weighted sum of the `count` of the symbols in the `symbolSet` (for the symbols that was successfully converted to `String` instances)

Example setup:

```
struct Item {
    let value: Int
    init(_ value: Int) { self.value = value }
}

let symbolDictionary = [
    "+" : Item(1),
    "-" : Item(2),
    "/" : Item(4),
    "*" : Item(8)
]

var symbolSet = NSCountedSet()
symbolSet.add("*") // accumulated: 8
symbolSet.add("/") // accumulated: 8 + 4 = 12
symbolSet.add("+") // accumulated: 12 + 1 = 13
symbolSet.add("-") // accumulated: 13 + 2 = 15
symbolSet.add("+") // accumulated: 15 + 1 = 16
```

Compute weighted accumulated sum with the chained `flatMap` and `reduce` operations (expected result: `16`):

```
let total = symbolSet
    .flatMap { $0 as? String } /* <- attempted conversion of each symbol to 'String'         */
    .reduce(0) { $0 + symbolSet.count(for: $1) * (symbolDictionary[$1]?.value ?? 0) }
               /* |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  |              |               If a key exists for the given symbol as a
                  |              |               String, extract the 'value' property of the
                  |              |               'Item' value for this key, otherwise '0'.
                  |              |
                  |   Multiply '...value' or '0' with the 'count' for the given symbol.
                  \
                   Add the product to the accumulated sum of the reduce operation.           */

print(total) // 16, ok
```

Comment: This looks very promising, I will be able to test this later this day.

Comment: @Koen happy to help. Consider including a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) next time you post a question (e.g. my `Item` definition and my `symbolDictionary` and `symbolSet` instantiations that I've included above), as this will make it easier for prospective answerers to help you out, which in turn will increase the change that you'll get a satiesfactory answer :)

Comment: Your example was pretty close to my case. Only `value` is actually a struct of two `Double` properties, so after some headscratching I replaced the `0` at the begin and end of the `.reduce` line with a "zero struct" with both `Double`s set to `0`. And all works!